# css selector properties not visible on inspecting it

Tags: css

I am writing css code in which I use a selector:

```
nav a:link{ 
      background-color: orangered;
      margin-right:30px;
      margin-top:100px;
}
```

Although these properties are applied on nav, but when I inspect, it is not visible on style window (where we see different elements and dev tools). But when I use `nav{ different properties }`, they are visible there. What should I do?

Comment: That would be due to the `:link` pseudo class then, I suppose. And while Chrome dev tools (didn't check Firefox) allow you to explicitly put an element into the "state" for the other pseudo classes like `:hover`, `:active` etc., it doesn't appear to offer that for `:link`. Do you explicitly _need_ `:link` here? Maybe `nav a` will do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link The :link CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has not yet been visited. It matches every unvisited <a> or <area> element that has an href attribute. #howtousecssrandomly

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written above seems to apply styles to the  tag inside the nav tag and will not apply styles to the nav tag.

For applying styles to nav tag, you should be writing css like

```
 nav { css properties here...}
```